# ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

Ошибка при создании пользователя

> ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably corrupted

Пробовал mysql_upgrade

```
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.24, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

С ключом `--force` нет никаких изменений.

На англоязычном SO пробовал, но не получилось

Есть варианты ?

ОС: Fedora 27

---

UPDATE:

Пользователя создал после полной переустановки, но ошибка с БД осталась.

Comment: Ну так разберитесь, почему база битая. Самый простой способ— пересоздать базу (существующие пользователи потеряются).

Comment: базу пересоздавал каждый раз, потом импортировал из дампа

Answer (score 0):

После переустанок и перепрочитывания всех логов обнаружил, что были некорректные данные в wordpress. httpd был настроен на другую папку, из-за чего данные для коннекта к БД были не верные. Изменил в категории, на которую ссылается конфиг httpd и вопрос решился.

***Вопрос с ошибкой из вопроса решился полной переустановкой mysql.***

Для установки WP рекомендую использовать [официальную инструкцию](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?bu=1aoq&from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=3128.jqx0t9A43qAAuNMlKhURDkKp81vAom5B3xGdGz6LyfElFv_DYR6rYREkSS1Fd1Sg.212c7addbdd8d19f5085ca17c0ebcdcd1962ac1d&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9dFa2ePbDzX73vlVaRPXYNfb0wz_Ps4kDyo51ZiEnvjKdVnF9IXR7Jr99qqvcxGIELNtlLuNwOtKxgzdBHbQKEI_vTN0WZRZVzdgh9SapM83fb3b6xJ_A4g,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk9yzKd9YIesTd3a7Jh6kfSvj81arGvoiFXpYh6yPvz371LUh3WSgUo25LtznAtvZBTHaZk08Crihq5HAQhroZ0Sdk3_hdXGMKw9XibOjqdB1svoAQBlzd-IvMWzXn_xvFhYyqkLAfnHVVTnCFkdAhibjh7tS_1mDAz1tktWkuAhlpFUg_NcA3veg6b3Vq5GJEC7VjiB-Zg9y9ll5zQ-MyddetvZ69HQbykq05_0lAy_BLdX1dg0CIOpi4rafYFzsgzjvMmiGs0lwSL2sNrreBG1x6O17_7rpfrvSIaMsPYduUoYctZ6DPH-Uek1SCbyaWaTJsisfGHu70XyjyU1fQqfjkBWZLxPIpSK06hr7CfAXfoVcZUkfIWA4j7b8CoD1oIUPYvi1Xz2kRTfKQGyZDWnhSCGKgEdMdLrZIAW1chBQBLTOhsBstarKAGB1hUoe_CmRPALI0mcwIzm4EdXw4R_6ls85ejr2bOue7dG5opCK4DQEThnVNwaWxSTnsBJNhah3K-f9mFZiCzq5svvL6BWPuOSi7VohwfIvZ3yu6w1enkdnYRZ4dtbwtlB6FUgTl6BwKE_Jr4HjNu5qZANuhDPlaNCqIl9tVMe46fN8Bo1uN8sVWLdG3JZxRznM04hN6LlwvDPlzFWFZu3cVw5necFK3ayWn0dYrlIphXbsDHun09DaDow9c_SzLK2lta0s1_vnnJfI_YGvZpgTqIW7AbdnrwDG7ME_GWUjRQHxsrfHzOp7BQlQ56lIkWnzP5_HQ3c7KnSUHQ6Pu9Wrr6XnbRpAAPAK8cbbLU0Hiim5R_D1-V04shgS83Y0gg1N6dwrojg1YCxhIS1ylJFIyiByZHPqNuPvwADi7c19AGBbni6gxPbNHMqMI3AcRYv5-XPioeu-YPT30Deud6QsGbiFn-7j2QK7DSPZdFArxTS-zQPuKaRFnYsN49e5iA_piEjzg4T0lGOm47tg&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXQTM0Z2pUZHFYM3dxRmhJeWxCMHY4Z2Roa3BEQXpYSGctQTRKY0pVWmpjck1CLVVLcGdPd3IyQUhCOW1mYVNyMkh0TC1rOENaTnQzVTlkQnhyTl9JSlQ4QllfeXpCY2QtaU8tVThMOE5xNGh1UzVPLTRPdVVhUC1PSGc2ZzdHZ3BRLCw,&sign=e7de7c068dfaddd19c2710a820a38921&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpfmwSlf_6ZUYZ2BPbpFQPbiziFLyVyJ-GEGHEj7AP0npxGiVK_OdqgJ2wDVz59LXW&l10n=ru&rp=1&cts=1563962647596&mc=3&hdtime=2835).